# How to execute SybaseIQ Load Command in Java

Tags: java, sybase, bulk-load, sap-iq

I am developing an application in Java. I have to execute Sybase bulk LOAD command through my code.

I am doing it like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(<url_string>);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
Boolean result = st.execute("load into table .... using client file.... ");
if(result) {
 SUCCESS;
} else {
 FAILED;
}
```

The command is getting executed successfully and the data is getting loaded to my table. 
The problem which I have is, I want to **capture the logs** which comes if we execute the same command through **dbisql**.

Using this approach I can only  the result weather it is successful or failed. 
Though I am able to create the log files using MESSAGES options of LOAD command but I was wondering if there is any other way to capture the **command line output** too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by executing the command through `exec()` method of `java.lang.Runtime` class.